# failed to push some refs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, push

Im trying to push to github 
I follow the steps:
(before these lines Im located on my app directory)

```
$ mkdir estaciones
$ cd estaciones
$ git init
>>Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/armandodejesussantoyareales/Documents/project_newbie/Estaciones/estaciones/.git/
$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "phase 3 estaciones"
>>[master (root-commit) 4462be3] phase 3 estaciones
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100755 README
```

(I don't know if that message is an error)

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:asantoya/estaciones.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

but always I have the same problem,late that I type that i got the next error

```
To git@github.com:asantoya/estaciones.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:asantoya/estaciones.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the remote repository already has a master branch and it has stuff in that branch that has been added since you made commits to your local copy. This is referring to the code visible at https://github.com/asantoya/estaciones

Start by cloning the repo from github, then adding your changes to it, then pushing:

```
git clone https://github.com/asantoya/estaciones.git
git checkout -b nameofyourbranch master
```

Add some files etc.

```
git commit -a -m "Your commit message"
git push origin nameofyourbranch
```

Comment: if a want to add all files the command is: "git add ." rigth?

Comment: how I can do for replace the existing files and directories of https://github.com/asantoya/estaciones

Comment: Yes, 'git add .' will add all of them. If you want to wipe the github files and start again, you could delete, then recreate that repository but you would lose history. Otherwise, delete all the files locally after cloning the repo (by using git rm), then add the files you want, commit them and push.